# how can I capture the stderr output when I call XMLGrammarCachingConfiguration.parseGrammar()?

Tags: java, xerces

I am using Xerces2 in Java and have an XMLGrammarCachingConfiguration. I am using it to parse an XML Schema (xsd) into a grammar pool by calling parseGrammar. It parses the xsd file fine, but it reports all error and warning to stderr (I am using Eclipse so this is captured in the console). I managed to change my xsd so that it would have a fatal error and this threw an XNIException that my application could catch, as expected.

I have tried using the method XMLGrammarCachingConfiguration.setErrorHandler(), and passing it a DefaultErrorHandler that I construct with my own PrintWriter. I have also tried passing in my own custom error handler that implements the XMLErrorHandler interface. Still it appears in the console, not in the file my PrintWriter is using.

This seems like it should be so simple. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

--edit:
I should add that I'm using a custom XMLEntityResolver, and the error messages that I want to capture are when my resolver can't resolve the entity, and so is returning null from its resolveEntity() method, which means the default entity resolver is trying to resolve it. i.e. the error messages come from the underlying default entity resolver.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to solve this. What I needed to do was create my own XMLErrorHandler, and then the trick was working out how to register it.

It needs to be registered with the XMLGrammarCachingConfiguration's XMLErrorReporter, however to get access to that you need to call

```
XMLGrammarCachingConfiguration.getProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/internal/error-reporter")
```

and then cast the Object that you get back to an XMLErrorReporter and call

```
XMLErrorReporter.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/internal/error-handler", customHandler);
```

It was as simple as that.